# Tshark and proper filter

Tags: wireshark

Using Tshark, I would like to apply filter on a wireless sniffer capture such that (both a & b are satisfied)
a) 802.11 beacons are present
b) Packets belonging to a certain wireless MAC address are listed.

Can someone help me with the command for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Capture filter:

```
wlan host 00:11:22:33:44:55 and subtype beacon
```

You can find more capture and display filters [here](http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2010/07/wireshark-wireless-display-and-capture-filters-samples-part-2-by-joke-snelders.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to apply filter on a wireless sniffer capture such that (both a & b are satisfied) a) 802.11 beacons are present b) Packets belonging to a certain wireless MAC address are listed.

"both a & b are satisfied" could mean either "I want packets for which both a & b are true" or "I want packets for which a is true and packets for which b is true".

If you mean the former, i.e. "802.11 beacons belonging to a certain wireless MAC address should be the only packets", then, if you want packets sent to or from the MAC address, the other answer's filter is the correct capture filter.  If you just want "sent to" or "sent from", use `wlan dst host` or `wlan src host`, respectively, rather than `wlan host`.

If you mean the latter, i.e. "802.11 beacons, and packets belonging to a certain wireless MAC address, should be the only packets", replace `and` with `or`.

For a display filter, replace `wlan host 00:11:22:33:44:55` with `wlan.addr == 11:22:33:44:55:66`, replace `wlan dst host 00:11:22:33:44:55` with `wlan.da == 11:22:33:44:55:66`, replace `wlan src host 00:11:22:33:44:55` with `wlan.sa == 11:22:33:44:55:66`, and replace `subtype beacon` with `wlan.fc.type_subtype == "Beacon frame"`.